# Extract and sort all numbers that appear after ',

Tags: python, regex

I am currently learning Python and I wrote the following code.
The code searches the string for all digits that appear after `',`, sorts them and joins them into a string.
I have a strong feeling that it can be shortened...
Can anyone suggest how?

```
s = "'bhhd',12 'kjubk',2 'bjki',98 'khjbjj',4"
res = re.findall(r"(',)(\d+)", s)
all = []
for r in res:
   all.append(r[1])

print(",".join(sorted(all, key=int)))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) behaves differently depending on whether the regex contains capturing parentheses.  If it doesn't contain capturing parentheses, then it just returns the matching text as a flat list.

So, how can you avoid capturing?  Just rewrite your regex to use a **positive lookbehind assertion**.

```
s = "'bhhd',12 'kjubk',2 'bjki',98 'khjbjj',4"
all = re.findall(r"(?<=',)\d+", s)
print(",".join(sorted(all, key=int)))
```

Comment: thanks - I thought of that this morning! I am understanding that otherwise (i.e. if I wanted both captures), the way I wrote it is as they say the 'pythonic' way ...?

Comment: If you want to capture, then you should use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to build `all`.

Comment: thanks! I thought that would be the direction but I wasnt sure how. I think I figured it out - the following code works, did I write it well? Let me know, thanks, David. `all = [r[1] for r in re.findall(r"(',)(\d+)"]`

Comment: That's fine. `re.finditer()` might be slightly better in that case.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I got that to work but I am not sure why that might be any better... Can you explain? Thanks!